# How to popup more data than alert box can display

Tags: javascript, alert

I have a a loop reading string array from page, but alert box cant contain all data

I am noob in JS, so I dont even know all popup-boxes

Any idea?

Edit: all data is stored in one string var (slashed with \n)

Answer (score 1):

Learn jQuery, and use the jQuery UI Dialog widget to display the alert as a modal dialog.

Comment: Umm, maybe I am lazy, but I am using JS once per year with very short scripts, so I would rather ask how to convert this script

http://pastebin.com/AqpsCLQL

Comment: prompt + \n in notepad++. Solved